# Field both NOT NULL and DEFAULT NULL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, null

This MySQL table had me perplexed for a moment:

```
mysql> desc quux;
+---------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| foobar                    | int(11)               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
(...)

mysql> show create table quux;
(...)
`foobar` int(11) NOT NULL,
(...)
```

Since the `foobar` field was never created with a DEFAULT clause, it gets automatically assigned DEFAULT NULL. However, at a first sight this looks like contradicting the fact that it was also defined as NOT NULL.

Then I realized that this schema aims to force to insert a value (and a non-NULL one) in `foobar` when adding a new record.

Is this an acceptable way to do so, or there are better ways?

Comment: If you are caught up in the apparent contradiction, read it this way: "by default, this column has no value; however, a value is always required so it must be specified."  There appears to be a logical inconsistency here, but there actually isn't, since `NULL` is not, itself, an actual value, but rather a marker signifying the absence of any value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's perfectly acceptable, it basically states:

> You **have** to provide a value for this, but I have no clue what that would be.

*If* you define a default value, you claim that this is a sensible value for any row that doesn't supply a value - which is not really feasible for most attributes.

Think about a column named `first_name` - you want to make sure a value is supplied but there is no way you can come up with a sensible default value for that. Or a column named `salary` in an employee table.